# Are types that are neither inductive nor coinductive needed for writing real world programs?

Tags: types, induction, type-theory, coinduction

Or it's just sometimes it's too hard to prove a type is a coinductive one?

I'm talking about a programming language that is total which means it's not Turing complete, and recursion are all wellfounded and corecursion are all productive. Does Turing completeness actually bring a lot more than in such a language?

Comment: Could you give an example of such a type? My first thought is a function type, but I feel like that isn't what you probably have in mind. Unless maybe you mean something like a type of lists that *might* be infinite, but could also be finite?

Comment: I mean something like Haskell's list, maybe that should be count as *both* inductive and coinductive, but that's what is in my mind.

Comment: I guess my next question is what do you mean by "really needed"? A Haskell-style list is useful because it can be finite *or* infinite. I'm not fully sure what you're asking here, so some clarification might help.

Comment: For writing real world programs.

Comment: I'm not sure if this really answers the question (only Turing-completeness is "needed" for writing real world programs and sometimes not even that), but having a list type that has both finite and infinite values can be useful. Generally, almost all the of functions that work on infinite lists also work on finite lists (`map`, `foldr`, etc). I'm still feel like I'm not totally sure what you're asking though...